# How can I cancel NSURLSessionDownloadTask which I resumed to get resumed my download (background) task which I created when last time I launched app

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsurlsessiondownloadtask, background-fetch

I created a background session and a download task which I wanted to be resumed after lunching app which was killed  by user.I found one way to resume that task, but there is a problem.I created new session and download task with same Url, at first it was good my old download task resumed but the problem was that the new task was created and I have 2 download tasks to download same objet(but I need only the old one). When I'm canceling the new task I'm not getting any notifications from old one.

Answer (score 0):

After creating new session and resuming download task with same url you can view the list of tasks on that session and stop the old one